# Ubuntu 20.10: Change from gnome to Cinnamon on the login screen and not just after login

Tags: gnome, login, 20.10, cinnamon

With this command and after login desktop choice:

```
sudo apt install cinnamon-desktop-environment
```

I am able to use the Cinnamon interface after login.
But after terminating the session or restarting the computer, the screen before login always remains that of the gnome interface.

How can I set Cinnamon even before logging in?

Comment: On the login screen you'll see a little gear down in the lower-right corner. Click on that and choose the desktop environment you'd like to use.

Comment: "With this command and after login desktop choice" means that I have already choosed the Cinnamon environment, infact, after the login I have the Cinnamon environment working properly, but not before of the login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao Mario.

- type `apt-get install lightdm`
- type `dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`, now you can select your login manager.

The next boot show you login manager instead of default.

Comment: Will this change the login interface (which is what I want)?
The Desktop interface is already that of Cinnamon and it already works.

Comment: Wow, lightdm is what I have searched. Thank you!